# How to setup solr 4.4 for production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, app-config

I am a a newbie to solr and RoR.

I have the production code for an RoR app. Solr is already configured but I need to change the DB connection to point to production setup. Upon researching I've found that changes need to be made in the solr/example/app/conf/app-data-config.xml. But not sure what changes.

Could someone please help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should not be going into production with example schema. There is just too much stuff there. Have a look for tutorials for smaller schemas (e.g. [mine](http://www.packtpub.com/article/creating-your-first-collection-simple)). But if you are stuck, you may just need to read on [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler), because it sounds that you are trying to import data from the database into Solr.